# Create new instance of an activity

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I am not very sure that if I am approaching it correctly. I want to do some network operation on the button click of an activity and then again relaunch the same activity with updated data.

When I am trying to do this using the below code :

```
new DataLoader(MainActivity.this,1,1).execute();
```

I am getting the memory leak error. I tried the below option as I read the same reference of the activity should be disposed.

http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android

I tried doing this :

```
try {
        GalleryDemoActivity.this.finalize();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new DataLoader(new MainActivity(),1,1).execute();
```

but this gave me the error as it find the instance of MainActivity as Null.

**Stcktrace:**
**10-02 22:33:59.060: E/dalvikvm-heap(18637): Out of memory on a 225808-byte allocation.**

```
10-02 22:33:59.060: I/dalvikvm(18637): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-02 22:33:59.060: I/dalvikvm(18637):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c976b8 self=0x400630c0
10-02 22:33:59.060: I/dalvikvm(18637):   | sysTid=18637 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074956408
10-02 22:33:59.060: I/dalvikvm(18637):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=890 stm=80 core=0
10-02 22:33:59.060: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-02 22:33:59.070: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
10-02 22:33:59.070: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
10-02 22:33:59.070: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
10-02 22:33:59.080: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1934)
10-02 22:33:59.080: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:663)
10-02 22:33:59.080: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at com.gurbani.sikhwallpaper.GalleryDemoActivity.getDrawablesList(GalleryDemoActivity.java:230)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at com.gurbani.sikhwallpaper.GalleryDemoActivity.onCreate(GalleryDemoActivity.java:71)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5013)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
10-02 22:33:59.090: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-02 22:33:59.100: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-02 22:33:59.100: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
10-02 22:33:59.100: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 22:33:59.100: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-02 22:33:59.110: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
10-02 22:33:59.110: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
10-02 22:33:59.110: I/dalvikvm(18637):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me in resolving the right way.

Thanks,

Aman

Comment: You are trying to relaunch the same activity you are in? Is the data stored persistently anywhere or are you trying to pass the data to the new activity?

Comment: Don't try to create an instance of an `Activity`, use the lifecycle methods and `Intent`. Run your task and update the `UI` in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: it is better to use `ApplicationContext` rather than `Activity`.

Comment: @zgc7009 I am getting the data from the network and storing in the sdcard. While getting the data to I am trying to reload the same activity.

Comment: extending on what @codeMagic said and the reason for asking my question, if you have persistent data you can just call `finish(); startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));`

Comment: @zgc7009 Tried doing the above solution but still having the memory leak.

Comment: The leak likely isn't directly related to that but how you manage something within your Activity on destruction. Can you post your stack trace so we can pinpoint the cause of the leak.

Comment: @zgc7009 Please find stacktrace

Comment: I don't see an error in your stacktrace

Comment: @zgc7009 Apologies added another line in the beginning of stacktrace.

Comment: That just states that your application heap is running low so more space is being reallocated for your app. It is usually a result of poorly managing bulky processes (which is easy to do, especially if you are new). What is the primary functionality of your activity? Do you dump your data after you store it on the sd or are you just letting it float in your app?

Comment: I am building a wallpaper app, I am downloading the images from network and displaying them in gallery. In this button click again I am downloading image and recalling the same activity. I expect the activity to pick new images and repopulate the gallery.
How can I dump data after use in the first place.